# Problem with <a href="#" class="secondary-content"> because href="#" not direct me to the right page

Tags: html, collections, materialize

**Problem**

The problems is based on the third line in the html code section.

When I click my edit button/icon i go to my front-page. I quess it because of http://localhost:xxxx/ and not http://localhost:xxxx/note. I had tried for example href=/note/# but then it just reload the note page and not open the secondary content.

**Html code for http://localhost:xxxx/note:**

```
 <div *ngIf="notes?.length > 0;else noNotes">
<ul *ngFor="let note of notes" class="collection">
  <li class="collection-item"><strong>{{note.title}}: </strong> {{note.description}} <a href="#" class="secondary-content">
    <i (click)="editNote($event, note)" class="fa fa-pencil"></i>  
    <i *ngIf="editState && noteToEdit.id == note.id" (click)="clearState()" class="fa fa-compress"></i>  
  </a>

  <div *ngIf="editState && noteToEdit.id == note.id">
    <form (ngSubmit)="updateNote(note)">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s6">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Add Title" [(ngModel)]="note.title" name="title">
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s6">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Add Description" [(ngModel)]="note.description" name="description">
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Update Note" class="btn orange">
            <button (click)="deleteNote($event, note)" class="btn red">Delete Item</button>
          </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `somedomain.com/some/path/page#domId` in URL makes browser scroll down to the element  `<someelement id=domId>`. This is commonly used to make scroll anchors on pages that have long content. Looks like you missusing it. I am not sure why would it "open anything" for you